# What do rings in The Lord of the Rings do?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Rings seem to be rather important in *The Lord Of The Rings*, but what do magical rings do in general? I don't mean the side effects of wearing the One Ring (invisibility, long life span) but the intended effects of rings. Based on [Saruman's creation of his own Ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/what-is-the-significance-of-sarumans-ring), they can't all be for the purpose of enslaving the races of Middle-Earth. Reading [this article on the Rings of Power](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rings_of_Power) suggest they help the wearer become awesome at tasks that the wearer would try and undertake normally (Dwarves gathering money, Gandalf's helping him lead).

Comment: @MattGutting I looked at that but those only focus on the Rings given by Sauron and I was hoping to encompass others (like Saruman's) as well.

Comment: @Daniel I don't believe Saruman has a magic ring. At least not one of the 9, 7, 3 or 1

Comment: @Liath --- Saruman [makes a ring of his own](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2358/4935), but I don't think its powers (if any) are ever made clear.

Comment: The only rings beyond those that are mentioned are the "lesser Elven-rings" that Gandalf describes to Frodo (in "The Shadow of the Past"). He describes them as "essays in the craft" and doesn't say anything else about them.