# Why didn't Sauron make another ring to replace the One Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring, sauron, tolkiens-legendarium

When Sauron returned to Mordor, he had his forge, Mount Doom, and probably all of the tools that he has used to make the One Ring, so why didn't he just create a second Ring? Was it because he put too much of himself into the One Ring?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79120/why-are-more-rings-of-power-not-forged/

Answer (score 10):

Because he didn't have the strength to create one. He put a big part of his power in that ring and since he lost the ring, he was weakened; thus he couldn't create another one.

> **And much of the strength and will of Sauron passed into that One Ring**; for the power of the Elven-rings was very great, and that which should govern them must be a thing of surpassing potency; and Sauron forged it in the Mountain of Fire in the Land of Shadow. And while he wore the One Ring he could perceive all the things that were done by means of the lesser rings, and he could see and govern the very thoughts of those that wore them.
>
> <sub>The Silmarillion, Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age</sub>

It was a risk he was willing to take and he did.The fact that he was weakened is mentioned in The Fellowship of the Ring by Gandalf:

> This is the One Ring that he lost many ages ago, to the great weakening of his power.
>
> <sub>The Fellowship Of The Ring, "The Shadow Of The Past"</sub>

Also, he did know that the One Ring wasn't destroyed, so his plan was to retrieve it, rather than create a new one. He knew that he was one of the really few creatures that could actually handle the Ring, so he was betting that it would get back to him eventually.

And keep in mind that this Ring was already the master of all the other Rings; so, to create an even more powerful ring would be really hard, if possible at all.

If I'm not mistaken, wasn't it mentioned on Silmarillion that the One Ring was his best craftsmanship? It would be hard to repeat the process and even harder to overcome the previous Ring.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: He only found out it wasn't destroyed when Gollum was caught snooping around Mordor.Prior to that he thought it had been destroyed

Comment: @turinsbane considering what happened to Sauron when the ring was destroyed, and as its creator he would have known what would happen if it was destroyed. I think it would be safe to say if it was destroyed he would have known about it.

Comment: That's a good point but in Gandalfs account to Frodo,Sauron believed it had been destroyed.